# How to add a roll dice function and a check guess function?

Tags: java

How to add a roll dice method and a check guess method?

My code:

```java
package oui;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class dicecalc {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        
          
      int numGuess;
        

                System.out.println("Enter the number the numer the dice will roll: ");
                numGuess = kb.nextInt();
                
                int dice1=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
                int dice2=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
                int sum = dice1 + dice2;
            
                System.out.println("Roll: total =  " + sum); 
                 {
                if (sum != numGuess) {
                    System.out.println("Sorry with a " + sum + " You LOSE :(");
                  
                } else { 
                    System.out.println("Woah!!! With a " + sum + " You WIN!!!!!!!");
                }
                }
          }
      }
```

I need to have this assignment resubmitted because I forgot those things but I don't know how to add it. Please help. I already have tried for days.

Comment: Be more specific. Your code has those "functions" in it already. Do you mean you need to write a method, other than main(), that returns a single dice roll or the sum or two dice?

Comment: 1. (For normal dice), better: `Math.random()*5+1)`

Comment: sorry i meant method

Comment: Okay. Should that method return ONE dice roll, or the SUM of TWO dice rolls? Does it need a specific signature?

Comment: The total of 2 dice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible basic layout. Replace the **???** with some code!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);     
        
    System.out.print("Enter the number the numer the dice will roll: ");
    int numGuess = kb.nextInt();
    
    int sum = sumOfTwoDiceRolls();

    System.out.println("Roll: total =  " + sum); 
    {
      if (!checkGuess(numGuess, sum)) {
          System.out.println("Sorry with a " + sum + " You LOSE :(");  
      } else { 
          System.out.println("Woah!!! With a " + sum + " You WIN!!!!!!!");
      }
    }
  }

  public static int sumOfTwoDiceRolls() {
    return ??? ;
  }

  public static int singleDiceRoll() {
    // Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min
    return (int)(Math.random() * (6 - 1 + 1) + 1);
  }

  public static boolean checkGuess(int guess, int numberToGuess) {
    return ??? ;
  }
  
}
```

Comment: TYSM ILL TRY IT

Comment: what do i put for the "???" sorry i just started and dont understand a lot lol (Like in general ;-;)

Comment: Well, `sumOfTwoDiceRolls()` needs to call `singleDiceRoll()` twice, add the two returned values together, and return that value: `return singleDiceRoll() + singleDiceRoll();`.

Comment: The `checkGuess()` method returns a boolean (true/false). Presumably we'd want it to return true if the two values match, and return false if they do not match. So you'd use: `return (guess == numberToGuess);`

Comment: Ty I’ll fix it rn